# ActivationException enterprise library on database connection

Tags: c#, enterprise-library-5

On my 64bit machine I have visual studio 2012 with update 4 and oracle 12 including ODP.net

When I try and make a connection I'm getting an exception. It doesn't matter what the connection string is, so I'm guessing it's not getting that far and it's a reference/dll issue?

typical call:

```
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>(AppSettingsHandler.ConnectionStringName));
```

My connection strings are as follows and both fail (it works fine on another dev machine):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DEV64" connectionString="Data Source=dev3;User Id=PISYSTEM;Password=xxx" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="DEV86" connectionString="Data Source=dev3;User Id=PISYSTEM;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The database is fine, as is the project as it's on another dev machine working fine so I presume it's some kind of configuration issue with Enterprise Library. Various searches just have random hints to incorrect dll's, etc but this is all out of the box stuff done within .NET using nuget. Seem a bit crap the Enterprise library having 'c:\home\chris' embedded, but I see this folder searching the internet so it must just be the way it is.

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "DEV64"
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 57
       at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 103
       at PI.Data.Services.DataManager.CreateContext() in c:\dev\PositionalImprovement\PI.Data\PI.Data.Services\DataManager.cs:line 20
       at PI.Business.Services.MapDataManager.getBatchList(Int32 statusID, String sortOrder) in c:\dev\PositionalImprovement\PI.Business\PI.Business.Services\MapDataManager.cs:line 44
       at PIClient.MainForm.loadBatchListGrid(Int32 batchStatusID, String sort_Order) in c:\dev\PositionalImprovement\PIClient\PIClient\MainForm.cs:line 855
       at PIClient.MainForm.openToolStripButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\dev\PositionalImprovement\PIClient\PIClient\MainForm.cs:line 350
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at PIClient.Program.Main() in c:\dev\PositionalImprovement\PIClient\PIClient\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name = "DEV64".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Database does not have an accessible constructor.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,DEV64

       Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
       NameRequested=DEV64
       TypeRequested=Database
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
            at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
            at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49
       InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The type Database does not have an accessible constructor.
            Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
            StackTrace:
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForNullExistingObject(IBuilderContext context)
                 at BuildUp_Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database(IBuilderContext )
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
                 at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
            InnerException:
```

any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Oracle ODAC client, reinstalled and as if by magic it worked. Despite me doing the exact same steps yesterday.

Comment: Probably the DbProviderFactory for `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` was not setup in machine.config.  The reinstall added it there properly.  Just a guess.